# JSON array sort by key value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to sort a a json array by selected key value.

```
    var Json = [{
        "post_id": 3,
        "distance": "2.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 3,
        "distance": null
    }, {
       "post_id": 4,
        "distance": "4.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 5,
        "distance": "3.130122"
    }];
```

I want to remove the index who have distance:null and want to sort it by distance order. expected json I want like this

```
 {
        "post_id": 3,
        "distance": "2.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 5,
        "distance": "3.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 4,
        "distance": "4.130122"
    }
and want to display only post_id as comma seperated **3,5,4**
```

Here I tried below code.

```js
var Json = [{
        "post_id": 3,
        "distance": "2.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 3,
        "distance": null
    }, {
       "post_id": 4,
        "distance": "4.130122"
    }, {
       "post_id": 5,
        "distance": "3.130122"
    }];
Json.sort((a,b)=> (a.distance > b.distance ? 1 : -1))
        var visiblePostId = Json
            .filter(function (item) {
                if (!isNaN(item.distance)) {
                    return item.post_id;
                }
            })
            .map((item) => {
                return item.post_id;
            })
            .join(',');
        console.log(visiblePostId)

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**Extra help: If somehow duplicate post_id come after sort How can I remove duplicate post id?**

Comment: filter first, then sort

Comment: That's not a "json array." It's just an array

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `map` and `join`?

Comment: @Nick I want to display comma separated post_id only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do what you want with 4 steps:

- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on whether distance is null
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) based on distance (note converting to numeric is not strictly necessary as JS will automatically do that when using the `-` operator on two strings (see the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-expressions.html#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator)))
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to the post_id
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) with `,`

```js
var Json = [{
  "post_id": 3,
  "distance": "2.130122"
}, {
  "post_id": 3,
  "distance": null
}, {
  "post_id": 4,
  "distance": "4.130122"
}, {
  "post_id": 5,
  "distance": "3.130122"
}];

const VisiblePostIds = Json
  .filter(({ distance }) => distance !== null)
  .sort((a, b) => a.distance - b.distance)
  .map(({ post_id }) => post_id)
  .join(',')

console.log(VisiblePostIds)
```

Note that if you might have `distance` strings which are empty that you also want to filter out, you can change the `filter` to:

```
.filter(({ distance }) => distance)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you give me little help like if duplicate post_id come then How can I remove duplicate post_id in filter?

Comment: @LemonKazi there are some good examples of how do remove duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)